# declare more then one ActionListener

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm learning GUI programming with Java right now and I'm trying to make my first owns Application.

I use ActionListeners in them. My Question is if it is more effective to declare just one ActionListener and reference it all the time or if I should declare one for every Button, TextField, etc. I use?

//pseudo code

either:

`myButton1.addActionListener(Main.getListener());`
`myButton2.addActionListener(Main.getListener());`

or:

`myButton1.addActionListener(new MyListener());`

`myButton2.addActionListener(new MyListener());`

Comment: This is more of a logical/strategic issue. You *could* make your main class a listener and simply add it to the controls. But you wouldn't want that to get to the point where `actionPerformed` became massive and unmaintainable/unreadable. Likewise, the opposite problem could pertain with multiple listeners, where later maintenance would be a matter of 'hunt the `ActionListener`'. One thing I would advise against is using anonymous inner classes as they tend to produce ugly code and ugly binaries and can cause coding difficulties. You should also look at `AbstractAction` as a possibility

Comment: Add a tag and mention of your Java GUI framework when posting here: JavaFX, Swing, SWT, Vaadin Flow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In both your examples your `actionPerformed` method seems capable of handing events from multiple sources. In that case a single instance is absolutely sufficient.

But what would you do if `actionPerformed` needs to do different stuff for each and every UI component? Either it would get pretty complex of doing it all, or you have many different actionlisteners that do one job only.

Reusability in general is higher if you create many small listeners, so prefer that pattern whenever you can. But the criteria is not every button but every actionperformed implementation.

Comment: So you're saying for a small application it's okay to use just one Listener, right?

And for more complex ones I should overload the `actionPerformed ` method?

Comment: What will you do it you got used to patterns for small applications but now face a big one? What will you do if you if your initially small project grows? I tried to explain that the programming model should be decided by reusability, not by application size.